# Add jvm args from build.gradle

Tags: gradle, jvm-arguments, minecraft-forge

I've got intellij setup with ForgeGradle (Minecraft mod development) I made a thing called a coremod (it only loads when you add the loading plugin class to an jvm argument) 
and I'm trying to add VM options without adding them from run configuration but adding it straight from the build.gradle file. ForgeGradle uses JavaExec for runClient{} and runServer{}. I tried doing something like this

```
runClient {
    args = [
        "-Dfml.coreMods.load=${loadingPlugin}"
    ]
}
```

But it didn't do anything. Is this even possible to do?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`args` is for your program arguments, use `jvmArgs` instead

```
runClient {
    jvmArgs "-Dfml.coreMods.load=${loadingPlugin}"
}
```

Comment: Also note, that using `=` will overwrite previous `args` (or `jvmArgs`). Just use the method with the same name to append arguments.